# How to make this function execute in time for the next code?

Tags: javascript, scope

How to make this garbage variable get read as the value of shipmentObjs in time? I know the console.log will read "undefined" but I want it to execute after the function. How? I tried several ways and I can't seem to figure out a way to make this happen

```
let garbage;

  db.scan({TableName: 'shipments'}, (err,shipments) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    // We got our shipments
    let shipmentObjs = shipments.Items;
    // Bring out the "done: false" shipments to display
    shipmentObjs = shipmentObjs.filter(obj => obj.done === false);
    garbage = shipmentObjs;
  });
});

// prints "undefined" . Must figure out a way to make it read shipmentObjs from the above code 
console.log(garbage);
```

Comment: This code is perfectly alright. It prints. What is your actual question ?

Comment: Sorry I changed the code to something else--- the real code. I just made a dummy one in the beginning to make it easier but I guess that dummy code works. So this is the real code now.

Comment: You need to understand that `db.scan` is async. Your `console.log` happened before the scan started. Asynchronous code can be handled by using promises or callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(garbage);
```

to work the above code fine you need to put it in he `db.scan` function.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First of all, the order doesn't matter, if you're calling async function - which db.scan() is. As @Amresh said, use promise or callbacks for this. Second problem with your code is what's happening **inside** the db.scan() func. I don't know what db library you're using, but most likely you won't receive any schema, if you'll get an error. Therefore, your code will crash on your `shipmentObjs.filter` try. You need to take care of this part. Simply return your error.